# Proportionally edit fcurve to match last keyframe with the first

Tags: animation, graph-editor, proportional-editing

I have a complex walk animation (downloaded from Mixamo). For each bone, it contains a number of keyframes, let's call them `x_1, ..., x_17` for an animation of length 17.

I would like to play the animation in a loop, but it wasn't created for it: for some of the bones `x_1` is far from `x_17`. For example, there is a root "Hips" whose Y location is moving forward. I would like to edit the animation such that:

- the last keyframe matches the first one (`x_1 = x_17`),
- the edit is made in a linear way, ie. there is no change to `x_1`, the change to `x_17` is `(x_17 - x_1)` and change to `x_9` is `(x_17 - x_1)/2`.

I tried doing it in the graph editor in these ways:

1. select `x_1`, cursor value to selection, select `x_17`, selection to cursor value, but this only edits `x_17` (and doesn't apply proportional editing, even when it is "on")
2. select `x_17`, `G Y`, eye-ball the position of `x_1` and move `x_17` to the same Y, and in the "move" window change proportional size to 16 (size of animation minus one).

[image: Doing the edit in the second way]

The second option works, but is tedious and imprecise. Is there a better way?

Comment: can you show us how you are trying to do the proportional editing in graph editor? maybe a video or at least a screenshot? for me it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wasn't able to find a convenient workflow for that, I wrote a very short add-on that does it [here](https://github.com/sygi/animation_in_placer).

Answer (score 0):

FYI, In Placer addon doesn't delete keyframes. It zeros out keyframes like you wanted. You can check the codes if you want. I don't know how you get the impression that it deletes the keyframes.

Comment: Thanks for the comment about [InPlacer](https://www.blendernation.com/2021/11/09/in-placer-a-free-blender-addon-to-make-your-animation-in-place/). As I commented there, I don't think it edits the curve in the way that this question was asking for: zeroing is not what I wanted (even though the gif shows the case where the resulting keyframes are zeroed).